# How to dynamically add new section to NamedDomainObjectContainer extension?

Tags: gradle

I want to dynamically add subversion repositories from json file to checkout through this plug-in https://github.com/seu-as-code/seu-as-code.plugins/tree/master/seuac-svn-plugin

this is sample from plugin page

```
subversion {
    SeuAsCodePlugins {
        url 'https://github.com/seu-as-code/seu-as-code.plugins'
        directory file("$seuHome/codebase/seu-as-code.plugins/")
        username svnUsername
        password svnPassword
    }
}
```

This is my implementation

```
def svn_repositories = ['url1', 'url2']

svn_repositories.each { svn_url ->
    println("adding repository $svn_url ")
    subversion << {
        name = svn_url
        url = svn_url
        directory = file("$rootDir/$svn_url/")
        username = 'user'
        password = 'pass'

    }
}
```

but i get this error -

Error:No signature of method: de.qaware.seu.as.code.plugins.svn.SvnPlugin$_configureSvnTasks_closure1_closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (build_9zpeh26t5p1wvuzbyjmrvyck7$_run_closure2$_closure3) values: [build_9zpeh26t5p1wvuzbyjmrvyck7$_run_closure2$_closure3@49f44947]
Possible solutions: doCall(de.qaware.seu.as.code.plugins.svn.SvnRepository), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)

any idea how to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by this way:

```
def svn_repositories = ['url1', 'url2']

svn_repositories.each { svn_url ->
    println("adding repository $svn_url ")
    def svnRepository = new SvnRepository(svn_url)
    svnRepository.url = svn_url
    svnRepository.directory = file("$rootDir/$svn_url/")
    svnRepository.username = 'user'
    svnRepository.password = 'pass'
    subversion << svnRepository
}
```

But want to use more 'groovy' style..